# Executing custom code when order status changes to confirmed in virtuemart

Tags: php, virtuemart

I have written a small php script that I want to execute every time an order status changes to "Confirmed".

Ι'm aware that I can put it directly in the order.php file, however doing so will delete my script when virtuemart gets updated.
Is there any other solution?

Comment: a cron job perhaps?

Comment: @rilcon42 No, i would like for the code to be executed immediately on order change status. I'm searching for something like hooks of woocommerce